# Using different namespaces models for Resources in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

love the Resources function in Laravel 5.5 which creates at resource prettier for a Model, but I have all my models stored in `/App/Models/*` instead of directly in the `App/*`-folder. 
This is causing the `App/Http/Resources/*` not to work.

Results in a `"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$map"`

This is caused because I stored my Models in a different folder which he can't map to by guessing.

Where and how to define the different placing of the Model?

Comment: Absolutely no need to down vote my answer. I pointed you in the right direction regarding the question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand of your problem you have to inject the Model instance in the resource constructor, there is no magical autobinding, i.e.:

```
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;

Route::get('/user', function () {
    return new UserResource(User::find(1));
});
```

I dont see any problem here, even with namespaced Models.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of the process you used to move the models to the new `Models` directory, so check a few things:

**Namespace of the models**

Each model has:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

**Check references in these files**

- app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
- config/auth.php
- config/services.php
- database/factories/ModelFactory.php
- Your Controllers

And change `App/ModelExample` to `App/Models/ModelExample`

**Update autoload classmap**

Add "app/models" to composer.json's classmap autoload section

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/models"
    ]
}
```

**Autoload files**

Run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Nope, that's really not the points. Models are working. Except that the new FoobarResource expects a '\App\Foobar', but I have my model in \App\Models\Foobar'

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload`?